# Android android:buttonStyle not applied

Tags: android, button, styles

I have the following code in my styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_deep_teal_500</item>
</style>
```

This is supposed to print the button background in Pink (#FF00FF) and text in teal, but it not applies to my buttons.

I had two kind of views, normal Button () and ButtonLinearLayout, that gets the current them default Button backgroundm, and apply it to LinearLayout.

But it's not changed when i try to apply it to my views / default button.

[image: Check image, top button is a ButtonLinearLayout, bottom one is default <Button>]

Comment: Uhmmm i checked and i can see the colors for background and textColor on layout editor, but not in device :S

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create a `res/drawable/button_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="@color/material_deep_teal_500" >  //text color when button is pressed
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#ff00ff"/>  //background color when button is pressed
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:color="@color/material_deep_teal_500"> //text color when button is normal
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ff00ff"/> //background color when button is normal
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

Now put `android:background="@drawable/button_selector"` in `xml` having button

Comment: Thanks for selector.

But it doesn't make any difference, i can see it on layout editor, but not in device :$

I'm using a DialogFragment with NoTitle if it helps

Comment: Can you not set this background programmatically to dialog fragment button? @alorma

Comment: I supose i can, but it's more complex of that, because I'm using a this buttonStyle to retrieve the button background drawable and applying to other kind of views

Comment: @alorma Try changing `parent="@android:style/Widget.Button"` to `parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Button` because `Widget.Button"` has no parent theme defined